# How to make a query that subtract value from a row and remaining value from next row order by date

Tags: c#, sql

I have a table in sql where items are stored with expiry date and amount, I want to make a query to subtract some of amount in amount column where expiry date is smallest one.

"For Example:

```
update table
    set amountcolumn = amountcolumn - amount
    where Expiry Date = MIN(ExpiryDate)
```

if entered amount is greater than the amount in column it should subtract all the value from row remove that row from table and remaining value should be subtract from next row where expiry date is next smallest one.

I have tried this query when user enter amount greater than the amount column it gives result in minus in amount column.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateInventory]
(
    @ItemName       NVARCHAR(50),
    @InventoryAmount DECIMAL(18,0),
    @TotalAmount     DECIMAL(18,0),
    @UpdatedBy      INT,
    @UpdatedName    NVARCHAR(50),
    @UpdatedDate    DATE,
    @UpdatedTime    TIME(2)
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ExpiryDate DATE;
    SET @ExpiryDate = (SELECT MIN(ExpiryDate) FROM Inventry)
    UPDATE Inventry 
    SET InventoryAmount = (InventoryAmount - @InventoryAmount), TotalCost = (TotalCost - @TotalAmount),
        UpdatedBy = @UpdatedBy, UpdatedName = @UpdatedName, UpdatedDate = @UpdatedDate, UpdatedTime = @UpdatedTime
    WHERE ExpiryDate = @ExpiryDate AND ItemName = @ItemName
END
```

I expect the output if row1 has 10 row2 has 20 and user enter 23 it should subtract 10 from row1 and 13 from row2 and row1 should be removed

Comment: Provide the table definition and sample data. What you want is known as FIFO method.

Comment: Follwing is the table that has column name itemname unit amount unitprice total amount and expiry date respectively and the values are 
row 1 has Potato kg 50 20 1000 2019-10-03
row 2 has Tomato kg 10 40 400 2019-10-03
row 3 has Tomato kg 20 40 800 2019-11-04
When i user enter 25 tomato it should remove 10 from row2 and 15 from row 3
since row2 is becomes zero it should be removed

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (partition by itemname order by expiry_date) as seqnum
      from t
     )
update table
    set amountcolumn = amountcolumn - amount
    where seqnum = 1;
```

Note:  This updates the rows with the minimum expiry date for each item, because of the `partition by`.  If you want the overall minimum date, you can remove the `partition by`.

Answer (score 0):

FIFO with `sum() over()` (sql-server).

```
create table foo (
    product varchar(100),
    amount int,
    expires date
);

insert foo values
     ('Potato',50,'2019-10-03') 
    ,('Tomato',10,'2019-10-03')
    ,('Tomato',20,'2019-11-04');
```

The query

```
--  update
declare @tomatoAmount int = 25;

with t as (
  select f.*,
  sum(amount) over (partition by product order by expires ) as runningtotal
  from foo f
)
update t set amount = case when runningtotal - @tomatoAmount <= 0 then 0 
                           else (runningtotal - @tomatoAmount)
                      end
where product = 'tomato' and runningtotal - @tomatoAmount <= amount;

select * from foo;

-- delete

delete 
from foo 
where amount = 0;

select * from foo;
```